# How to use or convert a GVIm color scheme for VIm?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

[Vivify](http://bytefluent.com/vivify/)'s corporation color scheme may look perfect to me, it does not quite match the screen shots once installed in VIm 7.3.

To ensure that was not an error of mine, I went back on the website to realise there were two versions ; the one you see, yellow and blue, for GVIm and another, purple and red, for VIm.
I opened the file and saw that colours are sometimes defined as "cterm". I guess this means that the same value will display different colours whether I run GVIm or VIm. This might have something to do with the terminal's color mode…

Too bad — my school will not allow me to use any other text editor than VIm or EMacs. And I definitely want this color scheme to work on VIm.

I checked CSApprox but, as the name (and the documentation) implies, it is a workaround with approximative results. I also checked CSExact but, as the documentation explains, it can be a source of issues.

I would really like to have corporate's GVIm colors on VIm. Is there any converter or way to manually convert the GVIm part for VIm ? Since Google is not my friend this time…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already found the canonical solution - *CSApprox*, which converts the 24-bit RGB values used in GVIM colorschemes to the nearest available color in a (maximum 8-bit) color terminal. *CSExact* tries to modify the terminal's color definition for exact color reproduction. Depending on the terminal and environment, this can just work, or be finicky.

I only know of one other option: Using a terminal that has full RGB support (I think it's in KDE's *Konsole*), and a Vim that supports that (I remember such patches being proposed; dunno whether it's already incorporated).

For me personally, the approximate solution by CSApprox is more than enough <sub><sup>(I'm a programmer, not a graphics artist, and this is a text editor for heaven's sake)</sup></sub>, and it's easy to use (I use the static one-time conversion).

Comment: CSExact behaviour can result in serious issues if the terminal's mode is not supported. I won't be able to use Konsole as I develop on a Mac with the default Terminal (which is more than enough to me). Eventually, as I do graphics design too, I do not see the link between VIm and graphics design – I just want to have a good-looking working tool so that programming does not become a pain.

Comment: I meant that I don't see the difference between #FF5500 and #FE5401, so the colors I get with CSApprox are fine for me. Modifying the terminal's color table could work to reduce the discrepancies, too, but I don't know whether that's possible.

Comment: Thoughts clarified, I can more easily get your point now. Of course, a teeny-tiny difference of that kind will not be quite noticeable but if your screen has an higher than average color depth, you might end up noticing the difference. Since I have a recent Apple computer, the screen's color depth should be around 24 bits which is why I can end up noticing differences more easily. I'll go with CSApprox until I find a better suited alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Another approximation option: if for some reason don't want to install a plugin, you may use the python script from https://github.com/kanru/vim-colorscheme-converter to statically convert your colorschemes. Of course if you already have CSApprox, you can issue `:CSApproxSnapshot` command to save the converted colorscheme.

While you can't get 24-bit colors on a 256-color terminal, you may still tweak the converted colorscheme to look a bit better.